# How to update tag value for exported metric in micrometer?

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, spring-micrometer

Im using micrometer for exporting summery of third party api consumption.
Now I want to precisely count failed requests and export each failed request ids.
Invoking below method for each **restTemplate** exchange call.

```
private DistributionSummary incFailedCounter(String requestId) {

        this.registry = beanProvider.getRegistry();

        DistributionSummary summary = summarys.get(myCounter);
        if (summary == null) {
            Builder tags = DistributionSummary.builder("failed.test").tags("req_id", requestId, "count", "1");
            summary = tags.register(registry);
            summarys.put(myCounter, summary);
        } else {

            String tag = summary.getId().getTag("req_id");
            String[] split = tag.split(",");

            summary.close();

            summarys.put(myCounter,
                    DistributionSummary.builder("failed.test")
                            .tags("req_id", tag + ", " + requestId, "count", String.valueOf(split.length + 1))
                            .register(registry));
        }
        return summary;
    }
```

This code insert new line to metric for each request.

```
failed_test_count{count="1",instance="localhost:8080",job="monitor-app",req_id="1157408321"}
failed_test_count{count="2",instance="localhost:8080",job="monitor-app",req_id="1157408321, 1157408321"}
failed_test_count{count="3",instance="localhost:8080",job="monitor-app",req_id="1157408321, 1157408321, 1157408321"}
```

Problem is this metric size is increased with many requests.
Is there way to remove or replace same tag and export only one dynamic metric with updated req_ids ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can not remove or update **tags**, cause they are immutable. One way is to unregister current meter. used below method to removed registered meter and applied new one.

```
registry.remove(summary.getId());
```

This produces one line metric.

```
failed_test_count{count="4",instance="localhost:8080",job="monitor-app",req_id="1157408321, 58500184, 58500184, 58500184"}
```